# Missing return statement with switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, return

```
public AlertStatus nextStatus(){
    int randNum = randNumGen.nextInt(3);
    switch(randNum){
        case 0: return new AlertStatusGreen();
        case 1: return new AlertStatusYellow();
        case 2: return new AlertStatusRed();
        default: System.out.println("ERROR: no random number.");
    }
}
```

This is a method in one of the classes for a program I have to make for school.
The switch takes a random integer and uses it to return an object of a certain class that is derived from the class AlertStatus.

For some reason I keep getting an error saying "missing return statement }" for line 9 of the above block of code (the very last line in the above code). I don't understand why it's saying this though seeing as I already have return statements for each case.

Comment: What would it return if the number is 4? (Yes, the number *can't* be 4, *but* the compiler isn't smart enough to know that)

Comment: In addition to what user253751 says, sometimes the compiler *cannot* know, regardless of how smart it is. If the type of `randNumGen` is an `interface`, and `nextInt(int)` is an abstract method, then the compiler has no idea of the actual implementation of `nextInt`. For instance, it could be that the implementation is resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `default` case you aren't returning anything. I think you wanted something like

```
public AlertStatus nextStatus(){
    int randNum = randNumGen.nextInt(3);
    switch(randNum){
        case 0: return new AlertStatusGreen();
        case 1: return new AlertStatusYellow();
        default: return new AlertStatusRed();
        // default: System.out.println("ERROR: no random number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved the problem. Just to clarify, if I have cases that return something in a switch, the default also always has to return something as well?

Comment: @Bernandion If your method returns something then every possible path through the method must produce a return value. It might be `null`, or it might be to throw an `Exception`. But it doesn't insert the instruction for you. The compiler can't determine that the return of `nextInt(3)` is in the range `0-2`.

Answer (score 3):

Default case has to return something. If you want to indicate an error best thing to do is to throw an exception indicating it.

```
public AlertStatus nextStatus(){
    int randNum = randNumGen.nextInt(3);
    switch(randNum){
       case 0: return new AlertStatusGreen();
       case 1: return new AlertStatusYellow();
       case 2: return new AlertStatusRed();
       default: throw new InvalidArgumentException("invalid argument");
    }
}
```